# Tactic to prove a boolean implication

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

Is there a tactic similar to `intros` to prove a boolean implication such as

```
f : nat -> bool
g : nat -> bool
Lemma f_implies_g : forall n : nat, eq_true(implb (f n) (g n)).
```

This tactic would pull `eq_true(f n)` into the context and require to prove `eq_true(g n)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me suggest to use SSReflect in this case. Because it already has the machinery you need. It does not use `eq_true` to embed `bool` into `Prop`, but rather `is_true`, which is an alternate way to do it.

```
From Coq Require Import ssreflect ssrbool.
Variables f g : nat -> bool.
Lemma f_implies_g n : (f n) ==> (g n).
Proof.
apply/implyP => Hfn.
Abort.
```

The snippet above does what you want, implicitly coercing `f n` and `g n` into `Prop`. Having executed the snippet you see this

```
  n : nat
  Hfn : f n
  ============================
  g n
```

but `Set Printing Coercions.` reveals that it's really

```
  n : nat
  Hfn : is_true (f n)
  ============================
  is_true (g n)
```

that you have.

Comment: Thanks. Is SSReflect standard Coq ? It looks like an advanced library developped at Inria.

Comment: Yes, SSReflect is now part of Coq distribution (namely ssreflect, ssrbool, and ssrfun modules). You can have more if you install mathcomp library (e.g. the basic part is available as `coq-mathcomp-ssreflect` OPAM package) -- it has ssrnat, seq and path (to work with lists) and even more very well designed libraries.